# How can we make a HashMap-typed parameter not editable?

Tags: java

Sorry my title may be misleading.

This is actually from one of my recent JAVA interviews, the interviewer asked me this question: if we have a parameter that is of type HashMap, how can we make sure that in the accepting method, there is no way the user can modify this HashMap (i.e., get() method)

I was saying using final during the interview, which the interviewer didn't appreciate at all, and I've searched online for this topic for a while still have no clue.

Could experts help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be coming from a C++ background, where making the parameter `const` would indeed prevent the method from modifying the object. In Java, `final` only prevents assigning to that variable; you can still call methods that modify the object itself.

So, for example:

```
void callingMethod() {
   HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
   map.put(1, 2);

   badMethod(map);

   // NullPointerException
   System.out.println(map.get(1).intValue());
}

void badMethod(final HashMap<Integer, Integer> map) {
   map.clear();
}
```

There are several ways to prevent this:

1. Make a [defensive copy](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15) before calling the method
2. Wrap the object in an unmodifiable wrapper using [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29)
3. Use an explicitly immutable type such as those provided by [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using of `final` doesn't prevent from calling methods on the reference. It only makes the reference itself unchangeable. So your answer was wrong.

My suggestion is to use generic (only for such interviews, not in programs!):

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap< String, String >();
    map.put("a", "b"); // OK

    Map< ? extends String, ? extends String > mapRO = new HashMap< String, String >();
    mapRO.put("a", "b"); // Compile error
    String value = mapRO.get("a"); // OK
```

As you can see, hiding generic types with `? extends ...` prevent "writing" methods (like `put`) to be called, because they usually need the type to be fully defined. But you can still call `clear()`, so it's rather very pool security concept.

Also you can use some wrapper, that would throw an exceptions on all "writing" method calls.

Comment: The intention of this non-straight answer is to use the question to show your knowledge about generics.

Comment: even i tought the same, but you do realize nothing can extend String ?

Comment: @PermGenError Yes, but it works! Java compiler isn't that smart :-)

Comment: actually javac is quite smarter than we think. it gives a warning, saying dude/dudette you are looking for something which extends String. As string is final no other class can extend it :P .. :)

Comment: @PermGenError I get no warnings compiling it with oracle javac 1.7.0_09 nor eclipse 3.8 JDT compiler. By the way, in the question there was no mention of the type `String`. So you can take any other type, that can be subclassed as an example.

Comment: ahh right, but i am pretty sure compiler generated a warning in jdk 6. Btw regarding the question, i am not sure if this is what OP wanted as he accepted other answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an unmodifiable Collection from that Hashmap like [here?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29)

You would then do:
`yourMethod(Collections.unmodifiableMap(yourHashmap));`
Using final only means that you wont be able to **overwrite** that reference with another reference in this block, it does not prevent **any method calls** on that object.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is immutable or unmodifiable map.

`Collections#unmodifiableCollection`

> It returns an unmodifiable view of the specified map. This method
>   allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal
>   maps. Query operations on the returned map "read through" to the
>   specified map, and attempts to modify the returned map, whether direct
>   or via its collection views, result in an
>   UnsupportedOperationException.

[*Reference*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the map you are passing using the [Collections.unmodifiableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29)

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.unmodifiableMap(myMap)` will return the read-only map. You should work on the Map object returned by this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways

1) this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);

2) defensive copying: this.map = new HashMap(map);